# Trouble finding sty file, even though it's in ls-R

Tags: bibtex

I'm on Linux (Mint 17.3 over Ubuntu 14.04), and have been reading around for how to get `bibtex` to understand a style file I've installed.

Following the output of `kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFHOME`, I added my style files (`aer.bst` and `te.bst`) to `/home/michael/texmf/tex/latex/local/`.

Then I ran `sudo texhash ~/texmf` to update `ls_R`, which now contains:

```
./tex/latex/local:
aer.bst
te.bst
```

However, my tex won't compile. If I go step-by-step, `pdflatex` seems to run fine, but `bibtex my_paper` gives error:

```
I couldn't open style file aer.bst
---line 19 of file round_two_paper.aux
 : \bibstyle{aer
 :              }
```

The relevant lines of my tex file:

```
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{aer}
% ...
\cite{label}
% ...
\bibliography{references}
```

There's no problem with the tex, since if I replace `\bibliographystyle{aer}` with `\bibliographystyle{/home/michael/texmf/tex/latex/local/aer}`, it compiles correctly.

`kpsewhich aer.bst` doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `ls-R` file from `TEXMFHOME`. It is highly unlikely that TeX Live is using a file name database there.

Then move your `.bst` files into

```
/home/michael/texmf/bibtex/bst/somename/
```

Comment: So I don't need to `texhash` at all? When I first started investigating, I remember there was no `ls-R`, but it appeared (obviously) after I ran `texhash`.

Comment: No. `TEXMFHOME` is, by default, not searched using a database. TeX Live searches the disk in this case. For other trees, it uses a database, but not for your personal tree.

Comment: Thanks! `kpsewhich aer.bst` is now returning the proper file and it compiles with just `\bibliographystyle{aer}`. Lots of confusing information out there :\

Comment: To figure out the right directory structure e.g. `bibtex/bst` rather than `tex/latex`, the easiest way is to just look at where the `.bst` files are in your main texmf tree. There are also ways of doing this with `kpsewhich`, but I think 'look and mirror this hierarchy' is really easiest, especially at the beginning.

Comment: I tried that, but I don't have any other `.bst` files :O; basically all the other `.sty` files I have are in `~/texmf/tex/latex/beamer`, which is why I tried `~/texmf/tex/latex/econ`

Comment: Yes but you can look in `$(kpsewhich -var TEXMFMAIN)/bibtex/bst/` or whatever.

Comment: I had to create that directory in order to use your solution

Comment: You mean the equivalent in your personal tree? That's pretty normal ;).

Comment: Oh, I thought you meant I might have been able to troubleshoot by exploring `$(kpsewhich -var TEXMFMAIN)/bibtex/bst/`, which I couldn't because it wasn't there

Comment: Sorry. Maybe you are on Windows, in which case it wouldn't work. And I never think.